# Merging 2 different DataFrame with different length

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrame Consists of time and price columns.

```
df1:                                 df2:

       Time1     Price1              Time2  price2   
    0   900        10                 900      10       
    1   910        10                 910      10       
    2   910        15                 920      10       
    3   910        20                 930      10       
    4   920        10         
    5   930        10
```

I want to create a new DataFrame df3 as the length of df2, and I also want to put df1['price'] in
it like below

```
df3:
Time2  price2   price1
900        10       10
910        10       15  
920        10       10
930        10       10
```

Where price1 shows the mean of price1 values for the corresponding time2 values like below

```
import statistics 
time910 = (df1.price1[1],df1.price1[2],df1.price1[3])

if df3.price1[1] = statistics.mean(time910):
   print('same')
```

```
same
```

I'm sorry if it's unclear, but could you advise me on how to do the above cleanly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try data frame merge with inner join. following would be logic you can work with! comment section gives more insight on code.

```
import pandas as pd
df_d={'Time1':[900,910,910,910,920,930],"Price1":[10,10,15,20,10,10]} # raw data as dictinary
df1=pd.DataFrame(df_d) # build a dataframe
df1_mean=df1.groupby('Time1')['Price1'].mean().to_frame() # group by Time1 and mean by price1
df2_d={'Time2':[900,910,920,930],"Price2":[10,10,10,10]} # raw data as dictinary
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2_d) #  build a dataframe
```

now merge will do the job:

```
result=df2.merge(df1_mean,left_on='Time2',right_index=True,how='inner') # merge,right df's as key so right_index=True
```

[image]